# Assigning 2 IP addresses from my ISP for gaming and web hosting

Tags: ip, wireless-router, web

I have a Windows Server 2003 that I want to use to host my company's website and a game server for MineCraft. I have a few links bookmarked in regards to setting up the web and game server but no idea what I do with the two static IPs.

Do I assign each network adapter the static IPs or do they go on the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are referring to *private* static IPs. These are the IP addresses for the machines within your home network. And yes, it is important you assign a static IP to the machines that host the Web server and the game player (I do not know whether we are talking about one or two pcs, here, but it makes no difference: you always have to go with a static IP).

The reason for this is simple: when a request for a Web page or for a game-related connection reaches your router, how is it supposed to know which pc that is destined to? By means of a rule called *port forwarding*, that states: any request arriving on port 80/25565 must be directed to pc1/pc2. Now, if the IP addresses of pc1 and pc2 were to change every time you disconnect and then re-connect, how could this rule possibly work? If instead pc1 is always at the same address (= static internal IP address), then the port forwarding rule on the router is very simple:

All requests arriving on port 80/25565 are to be addressed to the (fixed!) IP of pc1/pc2.

This way the router will be able to dispatch connections competently.

There is also the possibility that you were referring to static public addresses, i.e, one not beginning with 192, 172, 10. This is connected with how to identify your pc from outside you home network. If this is indeed the case, pls let me know and I will update this post.

Comment: Thank you. That did help, but I was referring to the static ip's that are provided by my ISP. Do I need to assign these to my router? Or do I just forward my server's ip static ip address to the specific ports for gaming and web?

Comment: The static IP provided by your ISp is the one that the Wan-side of your router will receive from your ISP. Then, you need to do port forwarding as explained in my answer. To contact your Web server (for instance) from outside your LAN, it will be enough to insert the IP given to you by your ISP into your browser, and you'll reach your Web server, likewise for the game. In other words: your IP sets your router's WAN-side IP to the value he communicated to you (so that you can reach your machines from outside your network), then you do port forwarding from WAN side to LAN side.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will want to Port Forward port 80 to the computer hosting your website and port 25565 to the computer hosting your Minecraft Server. (They can be the same computer). Then you can find [your external IP address](http://bit.ly/external-ip), which is where you will go in your browser to see your website and in Minecraft to play on the server.